# Translation of Google Earth Engine javascript functions to python functions

Tags: javascript, python, google-earth-engine

I am struggling to convert a javascript earth engine routine to python which is taken from this material [here](https://docs.google.com/presentation/d/1D7rezUHPElCfYWHMRNBChHjbEv6nXDD8xnh7_YgyK6A/edit#slide=id.g22bb639feb_1_27)

The javascript is as follows  I have included the input collections for context.

```
var l8 = ee.ImageCollection('LANDSAT/LC08/C01/T1_SR')
    .filterBounds(roi)
    .filterDate('2016-01-01', '2016-12-31');

// Load an Earth Engine table.
var blocks = ee.FeatureCollection('TIGER/2010/Blocks');
var subset = blocks.filterBounds(roi);
print('Size of Census blocks subset', subset.size()); // 409


var triplets = l8.map(function(image) {
  return image.select('B1').reduceRegions({
    collection: subset.select(['blockid10']), 
    reducer: ee.Reducer.mean(), 
    scale: 30
  }).filter(ee.Filter.neq('mean', null))
    .map(function(f) { 
      return f.set('imageId', image.id());
    });
}).flatten();
```

The part I am a bit stuck on is the conversion of the variable `triplets`, which includes various nested routines. My python version returns the error:

```
Unrecognized argument type to convert to a FeatureCollection: {'collection': <ee.featurecollection.FeatureCollection object at 0x7f29fb0e2b80>, 'reducer': <ee.Reducer object at 0x7f29fb10e670>, 'scale': 30}
```

The issue seems to be map(imfunc), which I assume is down to me getting the python function wrong.

```
def imfunc(image):
  return image.select('B1').reduceRegions({
    'collection': subset.select(['blockid10']),
    'reducer': ee.Reducer.mean(),
    'scale': 30})

def wrapf(f):
    return f.set('imageId', image.id())

triplets = l8.map(imfunc).filter(ee.Filter.neq('mean', {})).map(wrapf).flatten()
```

Can anyone shed light on where I am going wrong with the python conversion?

Answer (score 1):

In the original code, `.filter(...).map(wrapf)` is applied to the result of `reduceRegions`. In your translated code, you have instead applied it to the result of `l8.map()`, the outer collection instead of the inner, because you didn't keep it inside the outer `map` function.

This is a corrected translation:

```py
def imfunc(image):
  return (image.select('B1')
    .reduceRegions(
      collection=subset.select(['blockid10']),
      reducer=ee.Reducer.mean(),
      scale=30
    )
    .filter(ee.Filter.neq('mean', None))
    .map(wrapf))

def wrapf(f):
    return f.set('imageId', image.id())

triplets = l8.map(imfunc).flatten()
```

I also fixed the arguments to `reduceRegions` to use Python-style named arguments instead of a dictionary (this is necessary). There may be other errors I didn't fix — I haven't tested this code — but I hope it helps with learning how to translate.

Note that you don't need to change *every* function to a named function. Instead of `.map(wrapf)`  you can use `.map(lambda f: f.set('imageId', image.id()))`)

Comment: Thanks very much - the wrapf does not work, but the anon. lambda function does - I tried to edit your answer but it does not appear to have worked/been approved.

Comment: @crEO It should be equivalent as written, so something else is going on with the actual code you ran. What error do you see with it? (Your edit was [rejected by reviewers](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/28801139).)